# How to plot aggregated DataFrame using two columns?

Tags: pandas, plot, seaborn

I have the following, using a DF that has two columns that I would like to aggregate by:

```
df2.groupby(['airline_clean','sentiment']).size()
airline_clean  sentiment
americanair    -1             14
                0             36
                1           1804
                2            722
                3            171
                4              1
jetblue        -1              2
                0              7
                1           1074
                2            868
                3            250
                4             11
southwestair   -1              4
                0             20
                1           1320
                2            829
                3            237
                4              4
united         -1              7
                0             74
                1           2467
                2           1026
                3            221
                4              5
usairways      -1              5
                0             62
                1           1962
                2            716
                3            155
                4              2
virginamerica  -1              2
                0              2
                1            250
                2            180
                3             69
dtype: int64
```

Plotting the aggragated view:

dfc=df2.groupby(['airline_clean','sentiment']).size()
dfc.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True,figsize=(18,6))

Results in:

[image]

I would like to change two things:

- plot the data in a stacked chart by airline
- using % instead of raw numbers (by airline as well)

I am not sure how to achieve that. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to plot this dataset is to convert to % values first and use unstack() for plotting:

```
airline_sentiment = df3.groupby(['airline_clean', 'sentiment']).agg({'tweet_count': 'sum'})
airline = df3.groupby(['airline_clean']).agg({'tweet_count': 'sum'})
p = airline_sentiment.div(airline, level='airline_clean') * 100

p.unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True,figsize=(9, 6),title='Sentiment % distribution by airline')
```

This results in a nice chart:

[image]